# Can't alter database roles on a restored database

Tags: sql-server, restore, ssms, role

My SSMS Login (using an AD group) is allocated all server roles apart from sysadmin so I have quite a lot of access.

Using this Login, I have restored a database from its .bak file. However, my Login wasn't mapped to a User before this database was backed-up so when it is restored, I am not mapped to any Users. But, if I go into database Properties > Files, the Owner is me (although it is my personal Windows accounts not my AD Group Login I use within SQL).

I'm not sure how this affects things but it means I can still read/write to all the tables in the database, even though my Login is not a User in this database. I therefore then want to create a User on this database for my AD Group Login which works successfully. But then when I try to allocate this new User to any database roles, it says that I do not have permission.

What steps am I missing? What permissions do I need to allocate database roles to a new User on this restored database?

Comment: Are you doing it using script or from user properties? and what's your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Ronaldo I have tried it both ways but I get permission error either way. I am using SSMS v18.4.

Comment: I meant the version of SQL Server (`select @@version;`). To add a member to a database role you need any of these [permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions). Also, if you run `select is_member('db_owner');`, what's the result? [The doc says:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15#fixed-database-roles) *Members of the db_owner fixed database role can perform all configuration and maintenance activities on the database*

Comment: @Ronaldo SQL Server 2012. The result of the second query is 0, there are no members of the db_owner fixed role. I am trying to allocate someone to that role but unable to.

Comment: When you connect to the database and run `select user_name()` returns `dbo` right?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It doesn't. It returns my Windows login for my company, which is what I also see in Owner in Properties. I don't understand that because my Windows Login is not a Login setup on SQL, only my Login associated with my AD Group. In other databases, my Windows login is the Owner, and it does return dbo. So I'm not sure why this database is different.

Comment: Since your domain login is listed as the database owner but is not a member of db_owner role nor is mapped to the dbo user, i'd guess it is mapped to a login that existed on the instance where the backup was taken and doesn't exist on the current instance. could you try running [sp_changedbowner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changedbowner-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with your domain login as parameter to see if it corrects this situation?

Comment: @Ronaldo It's definitely mapped to a Login that existed on the previous and the current instance. My login wasn't mapped to a user on this database when it was initially backed up though. I executed `sp_changedbowner` and got this error: `Cannot find the principal '[domain login]', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.` with my domain login in the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I allowed my User to impersonate the dbo User so that I could then change fixed database roles.

```
USE [database]
GO
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON User::dbo TO [Domain\Login];

USE [database]
GO
EXECUTE AS User = 'dbo'
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [Domain\Login]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you're seeing your login as the owner of the database, I don't believe that information is accurate because of the output you got from `select user_name()` and `select is_member('db_owner')`. I think SQL Server is misleading you. The permission to read/write every table on the database could be explained by the [public database role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15#public-database-role).

## About not being able to add a new member to the roles:

Since you're not a member of `db_owner`, you won't be able to add a user on a database role. The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) says that:

> to change the membership in a fixed database role you need:
>
> - Membership in the db_owner fixed database role

## The problem taking the ownership:

When you tried to take ownership of the database (which is a way of being added to the db_owner role) you got the error

> Cannot find the principal '[domain login]', because it does not exist
>   or you do not have permission.

Because by being member of all server roles except `sysadmin`, as you described, doesn't grant you the `TAKE OWNERSHIP` or `IMPERSONATE` permissions and the [ALTER AUTHORIZATION for databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#AlterDB) doc says those permissions are needed:

> **Requirements for the person executing the ALTER AUTHORIZATION statement:**
>
> If you are not a member of the **sysadmin** fixed server
>   role, you must have at least TAKE OWNERSHIP permission on the
>   database, and must have IMPERSONATE permission on the new owner login.

You can check if you have those permissions from [sys.fn_my_permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-previousversions) running the following queries while connected to your restored database:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE')
WHERE permission_name = 'TAKE OWNERSHIP';

SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'SERVER')
WHERE permission_name = 'IMPERSONATE ANY LOGIN';
```

If no rows are returned, it means you won't be able to alter the owner of the database and to change that you probably need a `sysadmin` to execute the `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`  or grant you enough privileges to do so.

**Granting the needed privileges:**

```
GRANT TAKE OWNERSHIP ON DATABASE::YourDatabase TO [YourDomain\YourGroupOrLogin];
GRANT IMPERSONATE ANY LOGIN TO [YourDomain\YourGroupOrLogin];
```

Note: The login that is going to be the owner of the database cannot be an existent user on that database, or you'll get the following error:

> Msg 15110, Level 16, State 1, Line 1   
> The proposed new database owner
>   is already a user or aliased in the database.

---

**Further reading**: the 
[Chart of SQL Server Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#chart-of-sql-server-permissions) contains all the permissions you get from being a member of fixed roles (server and database level).

Comment: I can add my Login as a User for the database, and then I can grant full `ALTER` permissions to that User, including `ALTER ANY ROLE`. Also, I can grant `TAKE OWNERSHIP` to that User. Yet I still can't allocate that User to any of the database roles. I don't know why I'd need to impersonate that User given I am actually mapped to that User, I'd just be impersonating myself.

Comment: @Alex, [ALTER ROLE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) still won't grant you privileges to alter a **fixed database role**, it's in the doc under the [Permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) section. The TAKE OWNERSHIP is intended to become the owner of the database and it won't help you add a member to any fixed database role until you are the owner of the database. Were you able to run the  ALTER AUTHORIZATION after having the TAKE OWNERSHIP?

Comment: Can you advise to whom I need to ALTER AUTHORIZATION to? Of course, my Windows login is already the owner. If I try to give it to my Login/User, I get the following: `An entity of type database cannot be owned by a role, a group, an approle, or by principals mapped to certificates or asymmetric keys.`

Comment: @Alex, instead of Login/User it should be Domain\Login. `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[YourRestoredDatabase] TO [Domain\Login];` Keep the square brackets. First change the ownership to some other login of your DBA team or a local admin like `sa`, just to see that information change, then you change the ownership back to your login. Just remember that you need the `IMPERSONATE ANY LOGIN` permission to change the ownership to someone else.

Comment: Sorry that was a poor typo from me, I meant User/Login because they have the same name so I use them interchangeably. I attempted to ALTER AUTHORIZATION to my [Domain\Login] and received the error: `An entity of type database cannot be owned by a role, a group, an approle, or by principals mapped to certificates or asymmetric keys.` If I try to do it via SSMS properties also returns the same error. Interestingly it says in the error that a database cannot be owned by "a group" which is what this Login is, it's an Windows AD Group.

Comment: I think I solved this by granting IMPERSONATE ON [sa] to my Login. And then added my login to db_owner by using EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa'.

Comment: Nice, @Alex! It worked because the `sa` is a sysadmin, so the information on the doc stands correct: you can add members to a fixed database role if you are a member of `db_owner` or a `sysadmin` (which basically means you're a member of the db_owner).

Comment: I altered to a more secure method then which was to use GRANT IMPERSONATE [dbo] and then EXECUTE AS USER = 'dbo'.